# Force screen session to use specific version of python

Tags: python, anaconda, gnu-screen

I am using a screen on my server. When I ask `which python` inside the screen I see it is using the default `/opt/anaconda2/bin/python` version which is on my server, but outside the screen when I ask `which python` I get `~/anaconda2/bin/python`. I want to use the same python inside the screen but I don't know how can I set it. Both path are available in `$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You could do either one of the following:

1. Use a virtual environment (install `virtualenv`). You can specify
   the version of Python you want to use when creating the virtual
   environment with `-p /opt/anaconda2/bin/python`.
2. Use an alias:
   `alias python=/opt/anaconda2/bin/python`.

Comment: I have virtualenv but it's not working. where should I set the alias? in .bashrc, or .screenrc, or .profile ?